# Can't enable keychain sharing on Xcode 8.0 beta 6

Tags: ios, keychain, ios10, xcode8, app-id

So I'm trying to turn on the Keychain sharing in target capabilities, and I got this error message:

Add the keychain sharing feature to your App ID.

[image]

The entitlements file is changed automatically when I turn on the Keychain Sharing. Anyone knows how to fix the second step? I did not find Keychain Sharing options for App ID in member centre.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Forget it, restarting XCode fixed the issue...

Comment: This worked for me too - maybe add + accept it as the answer?

Comment: i got same issue, and restarting didn`t help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is still present in Xcode 8.1.

And, as Carles pointed in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006908/cant-enable-keychain-sharing-on-xcode-8-0-beta-6/40423382#comment67390373_39006908), restarting Xcode does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable development signing, then add correct provisionning profile in 
**Project setting > Choose target > general tab**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just enable keychain sharing in app id from developer apple portal and then create new provision profile.run using new provision profile. hope so it will work for you

Comment: There is no option to enable keychain sharing in the developer portal.

Comment: go to your app id on developer apple protal. edit and enable keychain sharing @T.Cervenka